# Spring boot [s0] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null,>

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu, tomcat, cassandra

I have a Spring Boot's application, using Cassandra DB 4.0, running into the ubuntu 16.0 with java 1.8_292.

when I start the tomcat 9, the message below appear in catalina.out log:

```
> 2021-05-11 22:57:49.614  WARN 1184 --- [s0-admin-1] c.d.o.d.i.c.control.ControlConnection: [s0] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, 
> 2021-05-11 22:57:49.628  WARN 1184 --- [ main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling re
> 2021-05-11 22:57:49.645  INFO 1184 --- [main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener: Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 
> 2021-05-11 22:57:49.692 ERROR 1184 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed
```

I checked and the CQLSH 6 is running correct :

```
Connected to SSP at 127.0.0.1:9042
[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.0 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v5]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

The nodetool status is ok:

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  414.45 KiB  16      100.0%            f457b508-1b91-456c-85bc-1a621c5c1d78  rack1
```

However the spring boot could not connect to Cassandra. And it gave me this erro **[s0] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null,** .

The cassandra.yaml and cassandra-env.sh are configurated the default with 127.0.0.1.

Does someone have any idea about what is happenning?

**Pom.xml**

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: upgrade `cassandra-driver-core` to latest version instead of 4.0.0 that is very old. Also exclude spark-cassandra-connector and spark dependencies if you don't need them

Comment: Thanks Alex Ott for your reply! I upgraded the {Cassandra-driver-core}. The Spark dependecies I need in my project. However the error continuous. This application ran very well in CentOs 7 at 5 months. We needed to change to Ubuntu and this error appears.  I don't understand, why it's happening.  Could you have another suggestion?

Comment: maybe you have a firewall on the node? Although usually it shouldn't handle the localhost traffic

Comment: I'll check. This new enviroment is in the AWS cloud EC2. I did not know that it interfere in the localhost traffic.

Comment: @AlexOtt, is this the same proble https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67526050/cassandra-with-spark-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-open-native-connection-to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Cassandra issue. Increase version of datastax/driver-java to 4.11.1. This version fixed the real problem : unexpected failure (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported request opcode: 0 in protocol 6).

For more details :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16636?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-2936